# Fingerprint sensor Acer Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, 22.04, acer

I was trying to configure the fingerprint on my acer swift 3 sf314-511 but i read online that acer don't provide drivers for linux unless you bought with it inside. Do everyone knows how can I do?
P.S. on the user setting doesn't appears any section for the fingerprint (that i think is LighTuning Technology Inc. EgisTec EH575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently no driver seems to exist for your model.
Your best chances may lie in the "fprint" project, which lists it under their unsupported devices list, but a [merge request](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/merge_requests/357) is under development right now. This [fprint issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/issues/494) is tracking the driver request for your model. You may want to keep an eye on that.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Thank You so much!